# How do we give default value to Primary Key fields in websites created through ASP.NET Dynamic Data (Entities)

Tags: guid, asp.net-dynamic-data

I am creating ASP.NET Dynamic Data Site (using entities) to manage master tables of my application. 
All my master table has a Primary Key of "UniqueIdentifier" in SQL Server. Where should I write "Guid.NewGuid()" in order to give default value (as new Guid) and to show them in textboxes bound with these fields?

Comment: See if my answer here helps you - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19438515/1564317

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I found the solution myself.
We need to open EDMX file, and ID property in each entity needs to be have StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed"